# Use getchar with pointer like char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, for-loop, getchar

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  char *q;
  int i=0;
  do{
    *(q+i)=getchar();
    i++;
  }while(*(q+i)!=48);

  int j=0;

  for(;j<i;j++)
    printf("%c",*(q+j));
}
```

I try to use in this way. I could compile. However ıt does not work .
My aim is that I wanna acquire char array (unlimited or limit will be defined by the user)
What should I do?

Comment: You didn't allocate any space for `q`

Comment: undefined behavior is not the way to go, and for such a small program, a `char[]` will do. Avoid dynamic memory when you can, it's slower and adds complexity. Bugs like complexity

Answer (score 2):

You should read a book on C.

You're just writing into random memory, causing undefined behavior.

You must allocate memory, you can't just write through a non-initialized pointer!

For instance, make it:

```
char buffer[1024], *q = buffer;
```

Then make sure you don't overstep inside the loop, of course.

Also, there's no point in writing the access as `*(p + i)`, when `p[i]` *means the exact same thing* and is much easier to read.

Finally, remember that technically `getchar()` returns `int`, since it can return `EOF` which is not a character.

Comment: @eznme Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

1st `allocate memory` for your pointer *q

```
  include<stdio.h>

  int main()
 {
    int a;

    char b[100];
    int i=0;
    char *p=b;
   while((a=getchar())!=EOF)
 {
    p[i++]=a;
 }
 p[i+1]='\0';
printf("%s",b);

}
```

Also you can try heap memory allocation

`char *p=(char*)malloc(40);`